# Is there a way to orderBy orOrderBy in laravel (8)?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have a scoped method on a laravel model:

```
public function scopeSort($query, array $params = []) {
    return $query->orderBy('read');
}
```

What I would like to do is say: if there are no items with read = true, then orderByDesc on id.

For example:

```
public function scopeSort($query, array $params = []) {
    return $query->orderBy('read')->orOrderByDesc('id');

    // Find all with a read of true or, if there is none, order the collection by id in descending order.
}
```

Does anything like this exist? Or is there some other way I can achieve this?

Comment: you can maybe try to use this https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orderByRaw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can chain your sorts :

```php
public function scopeSort($query, array $params = []) {
    return $query->orderBy('read')->orderBy('id','desc');
}
```

Example with :

```
ID      read
1       0
4       0
3       0
```

You'll get :

```
ID      read
4       0
3       0
1       0
```

Example with :

```
ID      read
1       0
4       1
3       1
5       0
6       1
```

You'll get :

```
ID      read
5       0
1       0
6       1
4       1
3       1
```

In the case where all read = 0, the query will sort by ID desc.
In the case where there are some read = 1, the query will sort by read, then ID.

EDIT: to be precise, the query will always sort by 'read' then 'ID', but I guess you'll have what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
public function scopeSort($query, array $params = []) {
return $query->orderBy('read')->orderBy('created_at','desc')
```

// or you can try with id as well

}